# Sample code for c++ WxWidgets blit an image to the canvas

Tags: c++, image, wxwidgets

I am trying to make a basic GUI using wxWidgets and wxFormBuilber to display a chess gameboard and chess pieces from a sprite sheet.  I would really appreciate some sample code for:

1. uploading an image from a file
2. blitting an image at a specific location

Comment: did you look at the image sample? did you look at any samples at all?

Comment: So far I used wxFormBuilder to make a static image and it was missing the GDIImage parameter.  I looked through the wxWidgets documentation for wxBitmap, wxImage, wxDC, but I was confused as to how to implement these into my code.  All Im looking for is like 2-4 lines of code that shows how to open an image and blit it to the screen.  I'm new to GUI programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simplest example I can think of.  This uses this [set of pieces](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Chess_Pieces_Sprite.svg/640px-Chess_Pieces_Sprite.svg.png) from wikipedia (licensed under the [Creative Commons license](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chess_Pieces_Sprite.svg)).  This example only draws the black pieces, but you should be able to figure out how to draw the white pieces with a few simple modifications.

[image]

```
// For compilers that support precompilation, includes "wx/wx.h".
#include "wx/wxprec.h"

#ifdef __BORLANDC__
    #pragma hdrstop
#endif

// for all others, include the necessary headers (this file is usually all you
// need because it includes almost all "standard" wxWidgets headers)
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include "wx/wx.h"
#endif

class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
    public:
        MyFrame();

    private:
        void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event);

        wxPanel* m_board;
        wxBitmap m_blackRook;
        wxBitmap m_blackKnight;
        wxBitmap m_blackBishop;
        wxBitmap m_blackQueen;
        wxBitmap m_blackKing;
        wxBitmap m_blackPawn;
};

MyFrame::MyFrame()
        :wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Chess", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(1000, 1000))
{
    m_board = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    m_board->Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &MyFrame::OnPaint, this);

    // Load the image.
    wxImage im("c:\\640px-Chess_Pieces_Sprite.svg.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);

    // Extract the images of the pieces from the larger image.
    wxBitmap b(im);
    m_blackKing = b.GetSubBitmap(wxRect(5,113,100,100));
    m_blackQueen = b.GetSubBitmap(wxRect(110,113,100,100));
    m_blackBishop = b.GetSubBitmap(wxRect(215,113,100,100));
    m_blackKnight = b.GetSubBitmap(wxRect(323,113,100,100));
    m_blackRook = b.GetSubBitmap(wxRect(433,113,100,100));
    m_blackPawn = b.GetSubBitmap(wxRect(535,113,100,100));
}

void MyFrame::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent&)
{
    wxPaintDC dc(m_board);
    dc.Clear();

    // Draw thie light squares
    dc.SetPen(wxColour(209,139,71));
    dc.SetBrush(wxColour(209,139,71));
    dc.DrawRectangle(0,0,800,800);

    // Draw thie dark squares
    dc.SetPen(wxColour(255,206,158));
    dc.SetBrush(wxColour(255,206,158));
    for ( int i = 0 ; i< 8 ; ++i )
    {
        for ( int j = i%2 ; j< 8 ; j+=2 )
        {
            dc.DrawRectangle(i*100,j*100,100,100);
        }
    }

    // Draw thie black pieces
    dc.DrawBitmap(m_blackRook, 0, 0, true);
    dc.DrawBitmap(m_blackKnight, 100, 0, true);
    dc.DrawBitmap(m_blackBishop, 200, 0, true);
    dc.DrawBitmap(m_blackQueen, 300, 0, true);
    dc.DrawBitmap(m_blackKing, 400, 0, true);
    dc.DrawBitmap(m_blackBishop, 500, 0, true);
    dc.DrawBitmap(m_blackKnight, 600, 0, true);
    dc.DrawBitmap(m_blackRook, 700, 0, true);

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; ++i )
    {
        dc.DrawBitmap(m_blackPawn, 100*i, 100, true);
    }
}

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
    public:
        virtual bool OnInit()
        {
            ::wxInitAllImageHandlers();
            MyFrame* frame = new MyFrame();
            frame->Show();
            return true;
        }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

On windows, the application will look something like this:

[image]

The important items demonstrated here are

1. loading the image.
2. extracting subbitmaps for the individual pieces.
3. drawing the pieces in a paint handler for the board.

Obviously, you should change the location of the png file in line 38.  If you want to take a [few extra steps](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Embedding_PNG_Images), you can embed the png file in your application.

I tried to keep the example as simple as possible, so there are many things that could be improved upon.  For example.  I used a separate bitmap for each type of piece. If you want you can use a [wxImageList](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_image_list.html)  instead.  In addition it would be better to use an [wxAutoBufferedPaintDC](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_auto_buffered_paint_d_c.html) in the paint handler.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!  I'm having one small problem.  my compiler doesn't like the m_board->Bind() line as it says Bind is not a member of wxPanels.  I checked the documentation and I also didn't see a Bind function under wxPanels.

Comment: Bind is a method of [wxEvtHandler](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#a03cc68ca201fb79c7e837919025be71a) which wxPanel derives from. If you're using wxWidgets later than 2.8.12 the Bind method should be available. If you're using 2.8.12 or earlier, you really should update to a more recent version, but you can use `m_board->Connect(wxEVT_PAINT,wxPaintEventHandler(MyFrame::OnPaint),NULL,this);` instead of the Bind command.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for your patience with me as I am relatively new to c++.  I was able to install the latest version and your program is running smoothly now!